# How to graph manually the rational functions of the form $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{2x^2+1}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, rational-functions

How to plot function of the form $f(x)= \dfrac{x+1}{2x^2+1}$ manually

What are the functions of this type called?  Is it a quadratic function?

Edit ..Thanks for letting me know that functions of this form are called rational functions

Please help me. I am new to this.

Comment: This is an example of a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function), the quotient of two polynomials.  Please edit your question to tell us what you know about the function (such as intercepts, limits, and so forth) and where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: This is rational function since it's the quotient of two polynomials. You can graph them by plotting the points $(x,f(x))$ in the plane, just like with any other function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint for the plot:** Here are some things one typically looks for:

1. **Intersections with axes.** To obtain these, we solve:

   $$f(0)=y, \text{ and  } f(x)=0,$$
   for $x$ and $y$ respectively.

2.1 **Local monotonicity.** For this one simply takes the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and determines the sub-domains in which the function increases/decreases.

2.2. **Turning points** . Points in which $f'(x)=0$ and such that $f'(x)$ "changes sign" (thanks @Henry).

3. **Local convexity/concavity.** For that, we study the second derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and solves the inequalities $f''(x)<0$ and $f''(x)>0$
4. **Limits.** Compute $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$.
5. **Discontinuities.** Look for possible discontinuities in the domain of $f$.

Can you determine these for your function of interest?

Comment: +1 As a sort of 2a, it might be worth mention turning points or at least points of zero derivative